# How to parse a specific json array?

Tags: php, json, parsing

I'm a php beginner. I've got this kind of JSON ?

```
   {
   "rows":
   [
    ["/page1.php","568"],
    ["/","78"],["/page2.php","4"],
    ["/page2.php","2"],
    ["/page3.php","1"],
    ["/search.php","1"]
   ]
   }
```

to parse json i use

```
<?php
    $json_file = file_get_contents('test.json');
    $parsed_json = json_decode($json_file);
?>
```

But i don't know to parse each page and number. Anyone can help me on this surely basic issue ?

thanks a lot

Comment: `var_dump($parsed_json)` - which won't be json anymore, by the way, it'll just be an plain-jane regular php array at that point - and follow the indentation of the output to see what "path" you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$parsed_json` will be an object, whose `rows` property is an array. The elements of this array are arrays, whose first element is the page name, the second element is the page number:

```
foreach ($parsed_json->rows as $page) {
    $page_name = $page[0];
    $page_number = $page[1];
    echo "Page #" . $page_number . " on " . $page_name . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, yes it's fine, nice answers with a little modification  : echo "Page #" . $page_number . " on " . $page_name . "<br>" (with  $page_name not only $name).